# This code prints the content before it. Why not after it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

    int aa = 0;
    char c = 'd';
    char a[4] = "hiii";
    char b[4] = {'d','e','f','g'};
    char d[2] = "sp";

    printf(b);

    return 0;
}
```

I know that this prints out `"defghiiid"`, because there is no null character, but why does it print it backwards? Shouldn't it be `"defgsp"`?

It should print out this: `"defgsp"`. Right?

Comment: There are no guarantees what will happen. If you pass a format string to `printf` which is not null-terminated, it is not a proper string and you invoke undefined behavior. Anything can happen. None of these variables are guaranteed to be allocated contiguously. The program might as well crash or do something unexpected.

Comment: You can check with valgrind the state of the memory to understand what is happening

Comment: You can try to use your debugger and inspect the actual layout of the variables. It is most likely different from what you expect. The layout depends on your the compiler, the compiler settings, the platform etc.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it's the other way round, this is an English spoken site, period. Question get regularly closed because they are not written in English, there is even a specific close reason for this. BTW your comment in german seems to be deleted now....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the code is *invalid*. It is not correct to pass a string *not* delimited by a null character to `printf("%s"`.

> why does it print it backwards?

I will guess you are compiling on X86 architecture.

It prints backwards, because the stack on x86 machine grows backwards and the string is traversed forward. The addresses of variables on the machine you are compiling are ordered by the compiler in the order of decreasing addresses values. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86 "The stack grows toward numerically lower addresses".

> It should print out this: "defgsp". Right?

The code is invalid. There is no "should". Anything can happen with such code. You might be interested in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).